# Obtener el tipo de codificación de un string

Tags: javascript, type

Dada una cadena de tipo *string*. ¿Cómo es posible saber qué codificación tiene?, es decir, si es "*utf-8*", "*ascii*", etc.

Si hago:

```
console.log(typeof(varString))
```

Obtengo que es *string* pero no su codificación.

Answer (score 0):

Como puedes ver en la [especificación oficial de ECMAScript](https://262.ecma-international.org/11.0/#sec-ecmascript-language-types-string-type), el tipo string usa internamente UTF-16 para guardar sus valores.
Esto no significa que sea el único tipo admitido al leer datos: si una llamada AJAX es respondida con texto, y ésta viene (por ejemplo) con el header

```
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

el navegador hará la transformación necesaria para leer correctamente los datos recibidos.